# split variable with a pipe separator and jq

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I'm trying to split a value in two values.
The value is:

```
HOUSE|CAR
```

And I do:

```
IFS="|"
read doc doc2 < <(echo $(callapi server:id| jq '.[].Documentation'))
```

but it gives me:

```
echo $doc
"HOUSE|CAR"
echo $doc2
<empty>
```

How could I get these:

```
echo $doc
HOUSE
eccho $doc2
CAR
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you write `echo $(something)` instead of just `something`?

Comment: Anyhow, getting towards the point of the question, see https://ideone.com/ytg8jd working as-intended. (Note that I'm setting `IFS` on the same line as `read` there, making the configuration change transient -- that's generally good form). Can you provide a [mre] -- code complete enough we can run it ourselves without changes to see the problem on our own system -- that _doesn't_ work as-intended? (Needing to provide our own `callapi` program disqualifies the code already in the question from being described as running "without changes", presently).

Comment: (btw, if you don't want literal double quotes in your output, then you should be using the `-r` argument to jq).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy . The callapi is a  funtion of a program that I use that call to an api and then I do jq to parse two of them. I think I cannot reproduce the exact example :-(

Comment: Right, but you should be able to write stubs that work well enough. For example, let's say you write `callapi() { echo '[ {"Documentation": "HOUSE|CAR"} ]'; }` -- that should make `callapi | jq` work.

Comment: And if the `read` code can split the output of a callapi stub like the above but can't split the output of the _real_ callapi, then that tells us we need to look for something interesting like lookalike Unicode characters that render as if they were a `|` but aren't actually the exact same codepoint. So the very act of trying to build a reproducer can often teach things about what the problem is even when it isn't successful.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it seems a problem with echo command because if I execute all api call it gives HOUSE| CAR, but i put echo $(....  gives me HOUSE CAR

Comment: I _did_ tell you not to use `echo` :)

Comment: (see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) over on [unix.se], and [I just assigned a variable; why does `echo $variable` show something different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) here).

Comment: (mind, it's also possible for your callapi program to check `isatty(1)` and emit different output based on whether its output is going to a FIFO; so there are additional possible bugs caused by the use of `$()` itself -- but you'd also get those problems triggered with `| jq` itself if that was in fact an issue).

Comment: ...anyhow, again, if you want a real proven-correct answer and not just a bunch of educated guesses, we need a [mre] we can use to see the problem ourselves.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If do without echo: read doc doc2 < <$(callapi server:id | jq -r '.[].Documentation'), It gives me: bash: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `<'

Comment: It's supposed to be `< <(...`, not `< <$(...`; in the example above the `$` is invalid syntax.

Comment: That is, `IFS='|' read -r doc doc2 < <(callapi server:id | jq -r '.[].Documentation')`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy perfect it works! Could you answer the question and I  gives you a vote if you want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)

Comment: (btw, I'm still not sure this is a great question insofar as it doesn't isolate things enough for me to be able to say exactly which of the several fixes in my answer was the one that was actually important to solving the problem and why; _with that level of isolation_ we could disambiguate from the many questions and answers already in our knowledgebase that touch on related issues; arguably, as it is right now, it could be closed as "too broad").

Comment: Also see [Split string into IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/397205/264812).

Comment: @Miguel7799, ...about the `echo $(...)` problem -- try `echo "$(...)"` instead; the quotes stop the shell from splitting on IFS when deciding what arguments to pass to echo. (But of course, it's more sensible not to use echo at all, which moots the issue).

Comment: ...and thinking about it, _that_ explains the problem: The unquoted expansion was stripping the `|`, so it wasn't there when the data got to `read`. Which means that the root cause is the one from the "Why does `echo $variable` show something different?" question.

Comment: You don't need to use [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) (a Bashism) for this, and using it makes it difficult to add error handling for the `callapi ... | jq ...` pipeline.  This uses only POSIX shell  features: `output=$(callapi server:id | jq -r '.[].Documentation'); doc=${output%%|*}; doc2=${output#*|}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are extra moving parts that can be removed to simplify how this code is executed.

```
IFS='|' read -r doc doc2 < <(callapi server:id | jq -r '.[].Documentation')
```

Note:

- Passing the `-r` argument to `jq` tells it not to escape content as JSON (preventing `"`s at the beginning and end of the output, and possibly other escaping of characters within).
- Passing the `-r` argument to `read` prevents it from consuming backslashes when they should instead be added to the results as data.
- Setting `IFS='|'` *on the same line* as running `read`, such that we're changing the IFS value only for the `read` command and not for the larger shell.
- Removing the `echo $(...)` avoids the set of bugs described in [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo), and also those in [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)